# Is memory released when reference count set to zero?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, reference, count

I have found that `[object_name retain]` increases that object reference count by 1 and `[object_name release]` decreases that object reference count by 1. `[pool drain]` applies release on all the objects it refers to.

Now I'm confused. What happens to an object when there is no reference to it?
`release` and `drain` just decrementing reference count so does memory is actually released on zero reference count or do I still have an object with a zero reference count?

I also found if here

`[pool drain]` // makes my Object str3 reference count Zero

`NSLog(@"%li",[str3 length]);` // it works, object may be not destroyed yet!

// other code here

But

`[pool drain]`

// other code here

`NSLog(@"%li",[str3 length]);` // not working, may be it is destroyed now!

Comment: Go read Apple's *[Cocoa Core Competencies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH27-SW1)*.  There is a lot of important information in there, such as this: “When the retain count becomes zero, the object is deallocated (destroyed).”

Comment: I get it ... system calls dealloc method automatically to free memory space on object being Zero reference counted! , thnks everyone for ur views!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the object will be destroyed after a zero retain count, and cannot be used anymore. Please refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) for more.

Comment: yes..but is there any way to check my object is deallocated from memory? ,as i can still call instance method retainCount with my object which has zero refernce count.

Answer (score 5):

Objects are deallocated when there are no strong references to then (i.e. when release lowers their retain count to 0).

Remember, though, that the `-retainCount` method is useless and you shouldn't call it.

Comment: re: the recommendation about using `retainCount`, I've found the following site useful [whentouseretaincount.com](http://whentouseretaincount.com)

Comment: as we call [object_name retainCount], so it is instance method, now if my object is deallocated on being zero ref. count , how still i'm able to call retainCount method?

Comment: @b_n_s: Sending a message to a deallocated object is undefined behavior. This means that any number of things could happen. It could appear as though the object still exists. It could look like you're messaging a *different* object. Your program could just straight up crash. Probably other things as well. What happens is pretty much a crapshoot. In your test, it looked like the object was still around, but that is because you were invoking undefined behavior. That won't happen reliably.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: No, that isn't right at all. No object other than `nil` will ever return 0 for its retain count. This is because only a destroyed object would ever have a retain count of 0, but sending messages to a destroyed object is illegal. As noted by Catfish_Man, `retainCount` is pretty much useless. It certainly can't tell you whether an object has been deallocated or not.